# How do I stop a result from a radio button from showing when the question is hidden

Tags: javascript, radio-button

I'm using radio buttons and I need to get the result for the second question to be hidden from the screen if I change my answer to question #1.

For example, if I say 'Yes' to question #1 and then 'No' to question #2 and then I go back up to question #1 and change my answer to 'No', question 2 will be hidden as it should, but the result from question 2 will stay on the screen along with the results from question #1.

```html
Is the accurate SKU on the LOS?<br />
<br />
Yes <input type="radio" onclick="javascript:yesnoCheck();" name="yesno" id="yesCheck">
No <input type="radio" onclick="javascript:yesnoCheck();" name="yesno" id="noCheck"><br />
<div id="ifYes" style="visibility:hidden"><br />
    Can the customer call the VM from their phone?<br />
    Yes <input type="radio" onclick="javascript:yesnoCheck1();" name="yesno1" id="yesCheck1">
    No <input type="radio" onclick="javascript:yesnoCheck1();" name="yesno1" id="noCheck1"><br />
</div>
<div id="ifYes1" style="visibility:hidden">
    Result of selecting Yes to second question.
</div>
<div id="ifNo1" style="visibility:hidden">
    Result of selecting No to second question</div>
<div id="ifNo" style="visibility:hidden">
    Result of selecting No to first question
</div>
<script>
    function yesnoCheck() {
        if (document.getElementById('yesCheck').checked) {
            document.getElementById('ifYes').style.visibility = 'visible';
        }
        else document.getElementById('ifYes').style.visibility = 'hidden';
        if (document.getElementById('noCheck').checked) {
            document.getElementById('ifNo').style.visibility = 'visible';
        }
        else document.getElementById('ifNo').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }</script><script>
    function yesnoCheck1() {
        if (document.getElementById('yesCheck1').checked) {
            document.getElementById('ifYes1').style.visibility = 'visible';
        }
        else document.getElementById('ifYes1').style.visibility = 'hidden';
        if (document.getElementById('noCheck1').checked) {
            document.getElementById('ifNo1').style.visibility = 'visible';
        }
        else document.getElementById('ifNo1').style.visibility = 'hidden';
    }</script>
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, the code below should do what you want. To help you understand the changes:

1. Let's say you have two elements, and one is a parent of the other, like this:

```html
<div id="parent" style="visibility:hidden">
    I am the parent
    <div id="child" style="visibility:visible">
        And I am the child
    </div>
</div>
```

The parent element will be hidden, but the child element will not be. If you want to control the visibility of an element, plus all of its children, you can instead use the 'display' attribute:

```html
<div id="parent" style="display:none">
    I am the parent
    <div id="child" style="display:block">
        And I am the child
    </div>
</div>
```

Now the child element is also hidden.

The other useful thing about using display rather than visibility is that elements with `visibility:hidden` still take up space on the page, while elements with `display:none` do not.

2. Using that technique, I moved your `ifYes1` and `ifNo1` divs inside the `ifYes` div. That way hiding or showing the `ifYes` div makes everything related to question 2 visible or invisible at the same time.
3. This is more a style thing, but if you're using two radio buttons, once the user has checked a button, then it's enough to just look at the 'checked' attribute of one of them.  If it's checked, then you know the other one isn't, and vice versa. Based on that logic, I simplified your if/else statements a bit. Personally, I think it makes the code easier to read.

Here's the revised code:

```html
Is the accurate SKU on the LOS?<br />
<br />
Yes <input type="radio" onclick="javascript:yesnoCheck();" name="yesno" id="yesCheck">
No <input type="radio" onclick="javascript:yesnoCheck();" name="yesno" id="noCheck"><br />
<div id="ifYes" style="display:none"><br />
Can the customer call the VM from their phone?<br />
Yes <input type="radio" onclick="javascript:yesnoCheck1();" name="yesno1" id="yesCheck1">
No <input type="radio" onclick="javascript:yesnoCheck1();" name="yesno1" id="noCheck1"><br />
<div id="ifYes1" style="display:none">
Result of selecting Yes to second question.
</div>
<div id="ifNo1" style="display:none">
Result of selecting No to second question
</div>
</div>
<div id="ifNo" style="display:none">
Result of selecting No to first question
</div>
<script>
  function yesnoCheck() {
    if(document.getElementById('yesCheck').checked){
        document.getElementById('ifYes').style.display = 'block';
        document.getElementById('ifNo').style.display = 'none';
    } else {
        document.getElementById('ifYes').style.display = 'none';
        document.getElementById('ifNo').style.display = 'block';
    }
  }
</script>
<script>
  function yesnoCheck1() {
      if (document.getElementById('yesCheck1').checked) {
          document.getElementById('ifYes1').style.display = 'block';
          document.getElementById('ifNo1').style.display = 'none';
      } else {
          document.getElementById('ifYes1').style.display = 'none';
          document.getElementById('ifNo1').style.display = 'block';
      }
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your thorough answer!